# Python : Finding power set without using any inbuilt function like itertools etc

Tags: python, powerset

I am trying to find the power set using bit manipulation.I can generate all sets but they are not indexable. I could not save it as a list of list. I tried to find the solution over the internet but could not get the relevant information.

Here is the code I used.

```
n = int(input()) # Size of the array
noteValue = []   # Array whose power set is to be found
for i in range(n):
    noteValue.append(int(input()))


powerSet = []
for i in range(1<<n):
    for j in range(n):
        if (i & (1<<j) > 0 ):
            powerSet.append(noteValue[j])

print(powerSet)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

Desired Output:

```
[[], [1], [2], [1, 2], [3], [1, 3], [2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Comment: I am having trouble understanding what (i & (1<<j) > 0) is checking for. Can you explain this?

Comment: @TirthRami both & and << are bitwise operators. (1<<J) essentially means (1* (2^j)). The complete  expression is checking, which bit is set (== 1). For complete reference of this problem, please visit [powerSet](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/power-set/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you can use a temporary list `sub` like this example:

```
powerSet = []
for i in range(1<<n):
    # Add sub list 
    sub = []
    for j in range(n):
        if (i & (1<<j) > 0 ):
            # Append to sub list
            sub.append(noteValue[j])
    # Then append sub to pwerset after finishing the inner loop
    powerSet.append(sub)

print(powerSet)
```

So, with this input:

```
2
2
3
```

It will output:

```
[[], [2], [3], [2, 3]]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, adding a sublist did the job.Got the desired output.

Comment: Glade to know. Happy coding